# VB6 type alias for long

Tags: vb6, alias

Is there any way to make a type alias for long in VB6? I know you can define user types as structures, but I need something similar to

```
typedef int mytypename;
```

in C where I am simply aliasing a simple type

Comment: That sucks. But thanks for letting me know

Comment: An Enum might give you what you want, depending on what that actually is.

Answer (score 4):

You can only implement such typedefs in a custom typelib, that can be consumed by VB6.

For instance `OLE_COLOR`, `OLE_HANDLE` are public typedefs declared in `stdole.tlb` and ready to use in VB6 as in `Dim clr As OLE_COLOR` being equivalent to `Dim clr As Long`.

Answer (score 1):

The only real purpose of this in C is to support portability. The C standard doesn't tell you exactly what the size of the various numeric types will be on all supported architecture, it just tells you the *minimum* sizes. Thus, since you might need to change the underlying implementation type, you use a `typedef` and a friendly name for the code.

This isn't the case in VB 6. The size of all the built-in types is well-defined and guaranteed not to change. It's part of the VB 6 specification. So there's really not much need for a `typedef` or equivalent.

I suppose *some* people use `typedef`s in C for readability, but I don't buy that usage. If it's an integral type, use the appropriately-sized integral type. There's no real readability benefit to:

```
typedef int ProductKey;
```

The only case where it makes sense is if you're defining a new, full-fledged type, like a color. But in that case, C programmers generally use a `typedef` to define the color type in terms of an integral type in order to save space and memory.

Again, that's irrelevant in VB 6 because you don't write code in VB 6 in the first place if you care about parsimonious memory usage and maximum speed. There are way more advantages to creating a structure (user-defined type), or even a class, that represents the color type, and then using *that* in your code instead. This way, you get all the readability benefits *and* type-safety (which is something that you *don't* get in C with a `typedef`). If you want to implement the `Color` type under the hood as a `Long`, that's your business.